Hibernate 6.5. hybrid Id generation with @IdGeneratorType
My goal is to implement a custom Id generator, that will decide in runtime (based on used db dialect), whether it shall generate identifiers using identity column, or sequence that is already present in database. For creating custom generators, Hibernate user guide suggests using meta-annotation @IdGeneratorType. There is an example, that uses this meta-annotation along with custom implementation of IdentifierGenerator interface. However, when I look into the implementation of IdentifierGenerator, I find the following comment (see in javadoc):
"Instances of IdentifierGenerator are usually created and configured by the IdentifierGeneratorFactory service. It's not usually correct to use an IdentifierGenerator with the IdGeneratorType meta-annotation."
So I find hibernate user guide a bit misleading. In javadocs, I found that @IdGeneratorType needs a class that implements Generator interface. What I want is that my custom generator implements both OnExecutionGenerator and BeforeExecutionGenerator and decides in runtime (on application start), which of the two strategies will be used. Is that possible using @IdGeneratorType? Are there some examples/clarifications that I am missing? (I am aware of the GenericGenerator interface, that kind of allowed this, but it is deprecated since 6.5)
I have a class implementing both OnExecutionGenerator and BeforeExecutionGenerator
public class BeforeOrOnExecutionGenerator implements BeforeExecutionGenerator, OnExecutionGenerator {
  private final BeforeExecutionGenerator beforeExecutionGenerator;
  private final OnExecutionGenerator onExecutionGenerator;
  private final boolean generateOnExecution;

  public BeforeOrOnExecutionGenerator(BeforeExecutionGenerator beforeExecutionGenerator, OnExecutionGenerator onExecutionGenerator, Dialect dialect) {
    this.beforeExecutionGenerator = beforeExecutionGenerator;
    this.onExecutionGenerator = onExecutionGenerator;
    // decide here based on dialect, if id generation should be using a sequence or identity
    this.generateOnExecution = dialect instanceof MySQLDialect || ... 
    logger.info("using dialect: " + dialect);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean generatedOnExecution() {
    return this.generateOnExecution;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean generatedOnExecution(Object entity, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
    return this.generateOnExecution;
  }

  @Override
  public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object entity, Object currentValue, EventType eventType) {
    return beforeExecutionGenerator.generate(session, entity, currentValue, eventType);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean referenceColumnsInSql(Dialect dialect) {
    return onExecutionGenerator.referenceColumnsInSql(dialect);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean writePropertyValue() {
    return onExecutionGenerator.writePropertyValue();
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getReferencedColumnValues(Dialect dialect) {
    return onExecutionGenerator.getReferencedColumnValues(dialect);
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getUniqueKeyPropertyNames(EntityPersister persister) {
    return onExecutionGenerator.getUniqueKeyPropertyNames(persister);
  }

  @Override
  public EnumSet<EventType> getEventTypes() {
    return EventTypeSets.INSERT_ONLY;
  }

  @Override
  public InsertGeneratedIdentifierDelegate getGeneratedIdentifierDelegate(PostInsertIdentityPersister persister) {
    return onExecutionGenerator.getGeneratedIdentifierDelegate(persister);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean allowAssignedIdentifiers() {
    return getCurrentGenerator().allowAssignedIdentifiers();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean generatesSometimes() {
    return getCurrentGenerator().generatesSometimes();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean generatesOnInsert() {
    return getCurrentGenerator().generatesOnInsert();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean generatesOnUpdate() {
    return getCurrentGenerator().generatesOnUpdate();
  }

  private Generator getCurrentGenerator() {
    if (generateOnExecution) {
      return onExecutionGenerator;
    }
    return beforeExecutionGenerator;
  }
}

Then I implement a custom generator in this way:
public class CustomIdGeneratorImpl extends BeforeOrOnExecutionGenerator {

  public CustomIdGeneratorImpl(CustomIdGenerator config, Member annotatedMember, CustomIdGeneratorCreationContext context) {
    super(new SequenceStyleGenerator(), new IdentityGenerator(), context.getDatabase().getDialect());
  }

}

Finally, I use the meta annotation @IdGeneratorType, to create my own custom annotation, which I am using to annotate the Id column:
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@IdGeneratorType(CustomIdGeneratorImpl.class)
public @interface CustomIdGenerator{}

This does not seem to work and still tries to insert rows with null ID columns

Do you need to keep using the deprecated GenericGenerator interface or you can use the new IdGeneratorType? If you can use the new interfaces, you can try to see the solution at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924224/jpa-how-to-call-custom-function-on-insert

I want to get rid of the GenericGenerator and use the IdGeneratorType annotation, but I dont think I can use the solution provided in the link . Problem is, I need my generator to implement both BeforeExecutionGenerator and OnExecutionGenerator as suggested in the Generator documentation. When id should be generated on execution, I need it to be generated using tables identity column. When id should be generated after execution, it should generated using existing sequence in db.

@VojtěchSýkora Why do you need the OnExecutionGenerator behavior?

@AndreySmelik I have two possible ways how to generate ids in my application, depending on used database. For some databases, I use named sequence. For others, I use identity column (mainly because sequence is not supported). My understanding is, that OnExecutionGenerator should be used when identity column is used for id generation.
